# I am trying to resize my Windows NTFS partition with Gnome Disks Utility

Tags: partitioning, gnome, ntfs, resize

```
Device                            Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/mapper/isw_ccdhechgd_Raid0p1 *         2048    206847    204800   100M  7 HPFS
/dev/mapper/isw_ccdhechgd_Raid0p2         206848 850673663 850466816 405.5G  7 HPFS
/dev/mapper/isw_ccdhechgd_Raid0p3      850673664 937713663  87040000  41.5G 83 Linu
```

I am trying to reallocate some free space on my NTFS partition for my Primary Linux partition. I am attempting to do this with Gnome Disk Utility
When I attempt to do this after clicking the resize and adjusting the size of the NTFS partition down to what i want; the Gnome Disks utility manager attempts to do the function then it Greys out. I am not sure if the application is resizing the partition in the background and there is simply no progress bar.

1. How long does it take to shrink a NTFS partition by 15 GB?
2. Does Gnome Disks Utility have a progress bar (in other words when the program greys out). Is it still running in the background? or has it timed out?

Comment: `How long does it take to shrink a NTFS partition by 15 GB?` no one can answer that. It depends on the disk speed and whether there are any data in that 15GB region which has to be moved

Comment: Most experienced users recommend using Windows Disk Management for changing NTFS partitions. I’ve never seen a convincing argument why you should do that. GParted and Disks do not have a reputation for screwing up but there is a certain logic to it. Suggest you use top in the terminal to see if it’s still consuming cpu resources

Comment: it still has been close to 12 hours should it take this long. The gnome disks application appears to be greyed out. I cannot close it. Is there a way to see it's progress? The partition I am trying to sink is on raid 0 SSD drives